# Cannot access admin panel after setting up django-oauth-toolkit

Tags: django, oauth, django-rest-framework

I had a pet-api (testing api) without authentication. I'm trying to learn how to implement oath2 to add security to my app.

> I'd like to access the models of my app through a request call using
>   the API but also through the Django Admin Panel.

I'm following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@halfspring/guide-to-an-oauth2-api-with-django-6ba66a31d6d

for setting up: `django-oauth-toolkit`

Tutorial says I should add this code to settings:

```
 AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
     'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' # To keep the Browsable API
     'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
 )
```

But when I run server, and try to access /admin, I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /admin/login/
No module named 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackendoauth2_provider'; 'django.contrib.auth.backends' is not a package
```

If I comment:

```
# 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackendoauth2_provider';
```

I can access the interface for the login, but says my user or password are wrong (they are not).

Commenting both lines I can access the admin panel without problems:

```
#AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' # To keep the Browsable API
    # 'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
#)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in code,

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' # To keep the Browsable API
 'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
)
```

There is a comma `(,)` missing after `'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` so it is taking both lines as single line, as you can see in the error.

So you needed to do just

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', # To keep the Browsable API
 'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
)
```

Now it will work...

Answer (score 1):

It's okay, mine is working good now without it. I am also following that guide. Just continue http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/applications.

BTW, I am also commenting the `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0']` and on the users/views.py, I changed all the `http://0.0.0.0:8000` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

And I now get these:

```
{
    "access_token": "C2qukd1zWz9aGSp652qbnpYjoT6ZRx",
    "expires_in": 36000,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "read write",
    "refresh_token": "UoI0r9J09F3kcXGO1q3KsYoGHQ9DBw"
}
```